# How to add Sudouser in Yocto

Tags: passwords, sudo, yocto, recipe

I'd like to add a new Sudouser in Yocto. Root password works well with changes and new user is added, but it is not Sudouser. How can I add Sudouser? I read a lot of Google articles and tried to copy them, but they all failed. I made a recipe but it didn't work and only added it to the local.conf is working.

1. Add extrausers. (new user : test1, password : pass11!)
2. Desable *debug-tweaks* to change the password of root.
3. Change root password. (None --> pass1234!)

The following is my code which added in local.conf.

```
# EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks package-management"

INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " usermod -P pass1234! root; \
                       useradd test1; \
                       usermod -P pass11! test1; "
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: First, having two users with full root permissions does not increase security in any way: you may want to consider if your plan (mentioned in a comment) makes sense. Second, "sudouser" is not a term I'm familiar with. If you want to use sudo you'd first need to add it into your image (it's not included by default because it usually does not make a lot of sense in embedded context) and configure it so that the new user gets the required permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Robert. I found the solution from Toradex engineer.

If someone has a problem like me, try the following.

1. Change root password.

Add the following in local.conf. I didn't use my recipe.

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES=""
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " usermod -P password root; "
```

If someone can't use ssh, please refer to [here](https://www.toradex.com/community/questions/26933/ssh-fail-after-adding-root-user-password.html?childToView=50910#answer-50910)

2. Add new user who has root permission.

```
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES=""
INHERIT += "extrausers"
EXTRA_USERS_PARAMS = " usermod -P password1 root; \
            useradd -ou 0 -g 0 newuser; \ 
            usermod -P password2 newuser; "
```

Maybe your user account can't use some command like "ifconfig" because your user account doesn't have the path "/sbin". Go to your Yocto code and find the correct file and add /sbin for your user accout.

```
r@p:~/oe-core/layers$ grep -r /etc/profile .
./meta-toradex-demos/recipes-core/base-files/base-files/profile:# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
./meta-toradex-demos/recipes-core/base-files/base-files/profile:if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
./meta-toradex-demos/recipes-core/base-files/base-files/profile:  for i in /etc/profile.d/* ; do
```

```
if [ "$HOME" = "/home/root" ]; then
   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
fi

if [ "$HOME" = "/home/newuser" ]; then
   PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

0) Where do you want to make your change?

In some config file, as above, or e.g. in an image recipe - see below.

1) You want to give root a password?

This might help:

https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/FAQ:How_do_I_set_or_change_the_root_password

2) And then you want to create another user who is member of the sudoer group or so?

Meaning more users will have root permissions.

Why?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. The answer of 2) is yes. I want to give root permission to another user. I want to chage config file because I tested new user in my recipe but I couldn't succeed. My root account alreay have a password. So this is OK. My concern is give a root permission to new user. My manager want to add another user but this user also have root permission like root account. So I have to add custom user like a root account. If you see my code, test1 is new user but test1 doesn't have root permission. Please let me know if you know how to give root permission to test1.

Answer (score 0):

So let's go to part 2) sudoers

This is what I did on my board as a quick test. Can you please try something similar and tell me if that's what you want? Once you confirm we'll see how to add this to OE/YP.

```
Resy (Reliable Embedded Systems Reference Distro) 3.0.1 multi-v7-ml ttymxc1

multi-v7-ml login: root

root@multi-v7-ml:~# sudo adduser anotheruser
Changing password for anotheruser
Enter the new password (minimum of 5 characters)
Please use a combination of upper and lower case letters and numbers.
New password:
Re-enter new password:
passwd: password changed.

root@multi-v7-ml:~# id anotheruser
uid=1001(anotheruser) gid=1001(anotheruser) groups=1001(anotheruser)
root@multi-v7-ml:~#

root@multi-v7-ml:~# sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/anotheruser

add this lines:
# users ins anotheruser group can do this:
anotheruser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

root@multi-v7-ml:~# logout

Resy (Reliable Embedded Systems Reference Distro) 3.0.1 multi-v7-ml ttymxc1

multi-v7-ml login: anotheruser
Password:
multi-v7-ml:~$ whoami
anotheruser
multi-v7-ml:~$ id
uid=1001(anotheruser) gid=1001(anotheruser) groups=1001(anotheruser)
multi-v7-ml:~$ sudo ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  media  mnt  my-core-image-minimal  opt  proc  run  sbin  sys  tmp  usr  var
multi-v7-ml:~$
```

Comment: Hi. Please see my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following. idh is my new user but it has many 'Permission denied' message. So I can't copy some files. But if you see my root accout, there is no error.

```
colibri-imx6ull login: idh
Password:
Last login: Sat May  2 12:13:20 UTC 2020 on ttymxc0
-sh: /etc/profile.d/utf8.sh: Permission denied
colibri-imx6ull:~$ cp /usr/bin/precept/*.* .
cp: can't open '/usr/bin/precept/SSID-psk.config': Permission denied
cp: can't open '/usr/bin/precept/flash.sh': Permission denied
cp: can't open '/usr/bin/precept/gettysburg10.wav': Permission denied
cp: can't open '/usr/bin/precept/run-htrc.sh': Permission denied
cp: can't open '/usr/bin/precept/wifi.sh': Permission denied
colibri-imx6ull:~$ ls /home
idh   root
colibri-imx6ull:~$
```

```
colibri-imx6ull login: root
Password:
Last login: Sat May  2 12:15:11 UTC 2020 on ttymxc0
root@colibri-imx6ull:~# cp /usr/bin/precept/*.* .
root@colibri-imx6ull:~# ls /home
idh   root
root@colibri-imx6ull:~#
```

I want to give the permission to new user like a root account. Please let me know if you know how to give this permission in Yocto.

Comment: We are not there yet to implement this is Yocto, since your problem statement changed from "sudo" user to "permissions". Can you please try to add your idh user just as I described below to your sudoers? Then this user can do something like "sudo cp", which should work ... but ... I think you have yet another problem with permissions.